# PHP: How to avoid page loading while using sleep()?

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I'm facing a problem for 2 days... I googled a lot but no solutions found yet... I'm doing a project named smart light... I'm using raspberry pi... I'm having 2 modules in that automatic and user control... In automatic control i have to get data from pir sensor and update the current status of the light in my web page... In user control the user gets the control to turn on and off the light from my web page... I have no problem with the user control... I have the main problem with the automatic control... I'm calling the python program( it controls the on and off of light with help of pir sensor) from the php program... In php program i'm calling the python for every one second for the page to be updated dynamically... But the sleep() in my php makes the page loading, loading and loading... My page is not viewing... But it's calling the python and the automatic on and off of light are correctly working... Pls help me... I want my automatic page to be visible without loading... 
My python coding is(sense1.py):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
PIR_PIN=26
relay_in=11
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN,GPIO.IN)
if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
    GPIO.setup(relay_pin,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(relay_pin,GPIO.LOW)
else:
    GPIO.setup(relay_pin,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(relay_pin,GPIO.HIGH)
```

The PHP coding is:

```
<?php
/* the 
database 
Connection 
coding goes here*/
function automatic()
{
    $db=0;
    while($db==0)
    {
        $sql="select control from Control";// this table to         switch over to user and automatic control
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $db=$row["control"];
        }
        if($db==0){
            $re=shell_exec("sudo python /var/www/python/sense1.py");
            sleep(1);//here is the problem
        }
    }
}
$q="update set contol=0 where sn=1";
$conn->query($q);
automatic();
?>
<!--here goes the HTML code-->
```

Please help me...

Comment: PHP works this way: A server gets a request, It loads the PHP code, parses it and then returns the result to the client _after_ the PHP-parser has finished executing. If you have an indefinite loop, or sleep, that means that the PHP-script has _not_ finished executing, and the result won't be sent to the browser.

Comment: Is there any way to keep on updating may page either with javascript or anything like that??

Comment: You should create a page with the HTML-markup and then update the data on it using Ajax (which would call your PHP script) every x seconds instead.

Comment: Ohh thank u... Please give me some example

Comment: Google "how to use ajax" and you will find many many examples.

Comment: Even when it's not the solution you want, you could use JSP to make this work, more easily, whitout mixing any other languaje. Like any Java-like language JSP could make the call to the process in a setting time, and like PHP you could work with it server side. Worth give it a try some day.

Comment: I used ajax to solve my problem... thank u so much